# How to solve system of equations containing trigonometry (in radians)?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, parametric, cycloid

I am researching about the brachistochrone curve, which is the inverse of the cycloid. The equation for the cycloid is :
\begin{cases} x = b(t - \sin\;t) \\ y = b(1 - \cos\;t)  \end{cases}

Based on this, I graphed the brachistochrone with the following equation:
\begin{cases} x = b(t - \sin\;t) \\ y = b(-1 - \cos\;t)  \end{cases}

However, when I tried to plot a point and algebraically solve for the 2 variables, with $t$ being measured in radians, I wasn't able to solve it and I need help.

For example, I was wondering how to find the $b$ and $t$ value algebraically that  would satisfy an x value of $20$ and a y value of $-5$. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvFSb.png) is a diagram of the situation.

**tl;dr  How do you solve this algebraically:
\begin{cases} b(t - \sin\;t) = 20 \\ b(\cos\;t - 1) = -5  \end{cases}**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for which variables want you solve the given system?

Comment: both the $b$ and the $t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{cases} b(t-sin\;t)=20 \\ b(1-cos\;t)=-5  \end{cases}
$$4(1-\cos(t))+(t-\sin(t)=0$$
Appart the trivial root $t=0$ leading to $b=\infty$ which isn't acceptable,  there is no closed form for the solution of this equation. The root cannot be expressed on the form of a combination of a finite number of elementary functions.

You have to use numerical calculus to compute an approximate value : $t\simeq -4.376072413012...$ and $b\simeq -3.75936382988...$

Before all, don't forget to prove that the system of equations has only one real solution with $t\neq 0$.